# Maven dynamic plugin configuration

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have in POM something like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                ....
            </resources>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <configuration>
                        ....plugin1 configuration.....
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <configuration>
                        ....plugin2 configuration.....
                        <configEntry1></configEntry1>
                        <configEntry2></configEntry1>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Profile has few plugins, those plugins have configurations and executions.
Depending on Jenkins job (I want to build desktop Java app on Win, Unix, Mac OS) plugin configuration can have small changes. For example, if I run the job for Mac the second plugin configuration should not have `configEntry2`.

I have to create profile for each job and have to copy paste 99 % of profile XML configuration. Is there a way to reuse the similar parts?

Is there Profile inheritance? For example `profile2`, `profile3` can inherit all plugins, its executions and configuration from `profile1` but I will override configuration for one plugin.

Or can I set dynamic configuration depending on property? For example: `<configEntry2 ifTrue="${property.name}"></configEntry1>`. Do not

Is there something like that?

Thank you for answers.

**EDIT** - adding a concrete example:

Profile 1:

```
<profile>
    <id>profile1</id>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <identifier>fxApplication</identifier>
            <appName>AppName</appName>
            <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass>
            <nativeReleaseVersion>${jfx.version}</nativeReleaseVersion>
            <jfxMainAppJarName>jarName.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
            <deployDir>${basedir}/deploy</deployDir>            
            <updateExistingJar>true</updateExistingJar>
            <manifestAttributes>
                <JavaFX-Feature-Proxy>None</JavaFX-Feature-Proxy>
                <Implementation-Vendor>vendor</Implementation-Vendor>
                <Implementation-Title>Title</Implementation-Title>              
                <Main-Class>package.Main</Main-Class>
                <JavaFX-Version>2.0</JavaFX-Version>
                <JavaFX-Application-Class>package.Main</JavaFX-Application-Class>
                <Created-By>Company</Created-By>
            </manifestAttributes>
            <jvmArgs>
                <jvmArg>-XX:-UseParallelGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx8G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40</jvmArg>-->
            </jvmArgs>
            <additionalAppResources>${basedir}/target/jfx/externalResources</additionalAppResources>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>             
                <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>create-native</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-native</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</profile>
```

and profile2:

```
<profile>
    <id>profile2</id>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <identifier>fxApplication</identifier>
            <appName>AppName</appName>
            <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass>
            <nativeReleaseVersion>${jfx.version}</nativeReleaseVersion>
            <jfxMainAppJarName>jarName.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
            <deployDir>${basedir}/deploy</deployDir>            
            <updateExistingJar>true</updateExistingJar>
            <manifestAttributes>
                <JavaFX-Feature-Proxy>None</JavaFX-Feature-Proxy>
                <Implementation-Vendor>vendor</Implementation-Vendor>
                <Implementation-Title>Title</Implementation-Title>              
                <Main-Class>package.Main</Main-Class>
                <JavaFX-Version>2.0</JavaFX-Version>
                <JavaFX-Application-Class>package.Main</JavaFX-Application-Class>
                <Created-By>Company</Created-By>
            </manifestAttributes>           
            <additionalAppResources>${basedir}/target/jfx/externalResources</additionalAppResources>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>             
                <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>create-native</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-native</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</profile>
```

the difference is only that profile2 doesn't have `<jvmArgs>`

How can I reuse 99% of xml script?

Comment: You know that a profile can be activated by a particular operation system ? See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Thank for you comment but I am not interested in profile activation, I am interested in configuration reusage or configuration dependence on properties

Comment: The question is for what purpose is that really needed and which configuration parts are different...or in other words which configuration parts are part of all configurations and which are special...

Comment: <plugin><configuration><jvmArgs>
                                <jvmArg>Here jvm arguments</jvmArg>-->
                             </jvmArgs></configuration> </plugin> In one case I need specify arguments in another case no arguments should be specified

Answer (score 0):

You can declare, of course, but also activate more than one profile at the same time. Create one with `<id>all</id>` that contains declarations common to all and further ones that extend this one, e.g. `WinUnix`, which contains `<configEntry2>`.

Then, for a Mac build:

```
mvn ... -P all ...
```

and for Windows/Unix builds:

```
mvn ... -P all,WinUnix ...
```

You could also use reverse logic, or a combination thereof, with [Deactivating a profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Deactivating_a_profile).

Answer (score 0):

To address your concrete example - I would suggest using a [property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) for the jvmargs. For example here's a simple POM that prints a message during the build:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven-profiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-profile-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <specialMessage>This is the default value</specialMessage>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <properties>
                <specialMessage>This comes from profile1</specialMessage>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>${specialMessage}</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Notice how the first `properties` tag specifies a default message when no profile is active. Later inside of `profile1` there is a specific value given to the property to show that `profile1` is active. This way the build tag and all its children are common/shared but the message changes depending on whether profile1 is active or not.

I agree with [Gerold Broser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715126/3284624) as well in that if you had a more complex scenario - say you needed to specify different plugins for a build - you can create multiple profiles and activate more than one. This way your common plugins and configuration can go in one profile while elements that are specific to a particular environment/scenario can go into another.

Hope this helps!